# Objective c: How to know picture's inspector information

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, image

I would like to know the information of a picture in the inspector. Is there a way to retrieve that information from objective-c.

[image]

The above screenshot is a sample of inspector window. I'd like to get the information of that window using objective c. Thanks !!

Comment: Does it need to come from that window specifically? Or do you want to get the info using the image as an `NSImage` object?

Comment: I would like to get each of picture's information from that window specifically (open that view by clicking "show inspector"). Would that be possible? What do you mean the NSImage?

Comment: Why from that specific window? And what exactly are you trying to make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could get most of those properties with `NSImage` or `CGImage`, I'd take a look at the ImageIO.framework.
It has the advantage that it can read the headers of several image formats without reading the whole image into RAM.
Apple provides a sample app that does exactly what you need:[ImageApp](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-DontLinkElementID_8)

Details about obtaining metadata with ImageIO can also be found in the Image I/O Programming Guide's ["Displaying Image Properties"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-DontLinkElementID_8) section.

To get file metadata you can use `NSFileManager's attributesOfItemAtPath::`:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary* fileAttributeDict = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:imageFilePath error:&error];
NSLog(@"creation date:%@\nmodification date:%@", fileAttributeDict.fileCreationDate, fileAttributeDict.fileModificationDate);
```